# Print current page of PDF document in Mac OSX Preview

Tags: macos, printing, preview

I'm using Preview to view a PDF document in Mac OS X 10.6. How can I print the current page that I'm viewing? When I select `File` - `Print`, there's nowhere to enter the page number. If I select `Print Selected Page`, it prints the **selected** page in the table on contents. This only works if I go manually search for the current page in the table on contents and then selected it - sort of a pain for large documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *selected page* is always also the currently viewed page when you view the sidebar as thumbnails. So change to that view e.g. by pressing `Cmd-Opt-2` to use that function by pressing `Cmd-Opt-P`. With `Cmd-Opt-3`, you get back to the table of contents -- unfortunately possibly changing selection.

---

You can enter the page number you want to print in the regular print dialog, see focused element below:
[image]

You just need to enter the page number displayed in the window title of the document.

Comment: View thumbnails works great. My print dialog doesn't has any of the page number options as you've shown.

Comment: @Wavy Did you press the disclose button on the top right so you have a very minimal dialog? If just these options are missing, consider asking a new question about it. It sure sounds odd.

Comment: Yup,that was it. I pressed disclose and all the options are now visible.